# Rails - Dump Request header gives Cant dump anonymous module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I dump the contents of the request headers in rails?

I tried `puts YAML::dump(request.headers)` but I'm getting the error

> can't dump anonymous module

. Also tried `logger.info request.headers.env` but Im getting huge content. I just need to know what's sent in the header. How can this be easily done?

Comment: Could you please answer these questions:  
What is the type of request object? 
How did you get request variable?  
Which library are you using to do HTTP request?

Comment: Im sending a REST api POST request. I have a problem in authentication and I need to check that the headers that I'm sending contain the right info. I'm not able to dump the request headers to check their contents though

Answer (score 1):

in your controller you can dump it

```
puts request.headers.to_yaml
```

yes, it can be a huge content. Then you should know, that it is only a hash, so you can do following and investigate more.

```
puts request.headers.keys
```

Comment: Im getting an error cant dump anonymous module. Any ideas on what is this?

Comment: @mrateb I do not know. What does it write, when you write only `puts request.headers`?